Changes to Community Building moderator team, and scheduling a moderator election
You may have noticed that some moderators on your site have lost their moderator access today. On July 8th, 2024, we released a new version of the moderator agreement. Moderators network-wide had 30 days to sign the new agreement. Of the 600 moderators network-wide, around 44 did not sign the new revision of the moderator agreement by the deadline. As a result, those 44 moderators’ diamonds were removed today.
While we are generally satisfied with this outcome, unfortunately some sites lost more moderators than others. On Community Building, there is only one moderator remaining as of today.
We are currently in the process of scheduling new elections where needed, and we will prioritize sites like Community Building that have been harder hit by this change. Until a new election concludes, Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees) will be checking on Community Building occasionally to assist with moderation. However, please be aware that it may take a bit longer than normal for flags to be handled.
We would encourage you to begin discussing and organizing your community for an election, and we’ll be around to schedule one soon.
In the meantime, we strongly encourage curators to use site curation tools to the best of your ability (up/down voting, closing, editing, flagging, and reviewing), in order to provide a good experience for users of Community Building in the interim. If you see anything that needs immediate staff attention, please feel free to contact us.

Hey Cesar / @Berthold - Any update about the forthcoming moderator election that was to be scheduled here? CB.SE appears to have missed the most recent round of moderator elections that seemed to target sites that were affected by the mod agreement change.

@Spevacus I'm going to ask the CMs who handle elections to answer that because I don't know :)

@CesarM, can you share any progress publicly?

@Rubén the update is that after this post was put up one of the mods that had been removed was reinstated (we had a grace period where mods who had missed the window to sign the agreement could sign it and be placed back in their role), which meant that Community Building had two mods instead of one and was no longer the most urgent priority for an election. We checked in with the site mods and they agreed that an election was not immediately necessary, so we told them we would circle back in the new year (which is now coming up soon).
